# Can my dog really understand me?

Tags: zoology

Are dogs capable to understands human language ( for example after order sit it sit because he know that word) Or can sence our order by body language and intonation if so why this type of communication developed only at dogs?

Comment: What do you mean by recognize human language? Do you mean "able to tell which language is being spoken" or do you mean "understand words in a specific language?"

Comment: I mean if he is actually capable to recognize my orders only in my mother language or he is used to my intonation and the sight for the specific order.  I thought the understanding of single word is came in hand with this question.

Comment: Your dog understand you facial and body expression and gestures along the tune of your voice and the actual word being said. If you change the word and keep the rest, your dog might still understand the rest. In fact, many dogs tend to have an easier time to learn gesture than vocal commands. My dog will sit, lie down, give the paw, go to his bed and twirle much more easily if I make the gesture than if I say the command.

Comment: I think tyou are right. But i remember experiment, where researcher tried to learn dog by giving him a reward. He lerned him to bring specific item by his order (i saw it in documentary but dont know name). Fact what i tried to explain that he said bring for example doll and the dog bring it to him (but with hard drill).

Comment: @Remi.b: WRT tone and body language, how does this really differ from humans?

Comment: It does not. Both humans and dogs use somewhat similar cues to interpret someone else attempt to communicate. Why?

Comment: @Remi.b: Because your comment seems to be saying that dogs respond much more to tone & body language than to actual words.

Comment: (https://www.petmd.com/dog/behavior/dog-brain-facts-understanding-canine-cognition) according to this remi.b you should be right, but i am not stil sitysfied with the communication part. Its kind of strenge things about that the dog evolve the abillity to communicate with us because we gave them food, and our love. But if dometication can do this with dog, why not with others ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some researchers say that dogs have the intelligence of a two-year old.

Many dogs can understand more than 150 words and intentionally deceive other dogs and people to get treats, according to psychologist and leading canine researcher Stanley Coren, PhD, of the University of British Columbia.

He is a reasonable and serious scientist who is biased towards overstating dog intelligence. he sais:

The average dog can learn 165 words, including signals, and the “super dogs” (those in the top 20 percent of dog intelligence) can learn 250 words, Coren says. “The upper limit of dogs’ ability to learn language is partly based on a study of a border collie named Rico who showed knowledge of 200 spoken words and demonstrated ’fast-track learning,’ which scientists believed to be found only in humans and language learning apes,”

Dogs can also count up to four or five,

http://www.apa.org/news/press/releases/2009/08/dogs-think.aspx